# Ubuntu package revision not found in GitHub actions

Tags: ubuntu, github-actions

I use GitHub actions with an Ubuntu 20.04 runner, and since last Saturday, started getting an error in Github actions log. I had not changed the yml config.

The error:

```
Get:79 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 proj-bin amd64 6.3.1-1 [88.8 kB]
Fetched 55.7 MB in 1s (61.8 MB/s)
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/curl/libcurl4-gnutls-dev_7.68.0-1ubuntu2.5_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 52.250.76.244 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
Error: Process completed with exit code 100.
```

I checked the [repo](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/curl/) and there's a bit different version available:

```
trying to fetch: libcurl4-gnutls-dev_7.68.0-1ubuntu2.5_amd64.deb
      available: libcurl4-gnutls-dev_7.68.0-1ubuntu2.6_amd64.deb
```

(`ubuntu2.6_amd64` vs `ubuntu2.5_amd64`)

How should I make the installer find this version?

Part of the yml config ([complete file](https://github.com/culebron/erde/blob/master/.github/workflows/python-publish.yml)):

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        python-version: [3.6, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9]

    services:
      postgres:
        # postgres stuff
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        fetch-depth: 0
    - name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        # some python packages
```

Comment: Please do not omit relevant information. Post the _complete_ yaml file.

Comment: @MichaelHampton posted a URL to the complete config.

Comment: It doesn't run `apt-get update` before trying to `apt-get install`!

Comment: @MichaelHampton thanks, indeed it was deeper in the config, tests passed. Please, post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error suggested the solution:

```
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Indeed, inspecting the YAML revealed that `apt-get update` was not being run. This should be run before installing software.

Comment: Somehow I did not notice the "run apt-get update" phrase until I read your answer. Too much focus and tunnel vision.